# Why is sum and product of a function a Function again?

Tags: functions

> Why is the sum and the product of two functions a function again?

Let, $f,g$ be two functions then why is $f(x)g(x)=h_{1}(x)$ and $f(x)+g(x)=h_{2}(x)$ where $h_{1}(x)$ and $h_{2}(x)$ are also other functions depending on $x$.

It is something so obvious but I cant come up with a reason why this should be the case.

Comment: It's the way it is defined.

Comment: $h(x)$ is only defined over the intersection of the two domains. If $a$ is in the domain of $h$, then there is a single value of $f(a)$ and a single value of $g(a)$ and product of two values always get another value, namely $h(a)$. Is the question "why is multiplication uniquely defined for every two given values"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the sum (and product) of functions is defined only for the intersection of the domains of a function. Now,

Consider two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ (and the mutual domain is $\mathcal{D}$), and let $s(x)=f(x)+g(x)$. Now, by definition of a function, at any $x$ in the domain $\mathcal D$, both $f$ and $g$ give a unique number. And $s$ will be the sum of the two numbers, which is also unique for two given numbers. Therefore, for any $x\in\mathcal D$, $s$ returns a unique value, and thus $s$ is a function.

You can extend this argument similarly to product case and the case with more than two functions.

Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)